# size limit for multiple cookies in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

As I have read many places the cookie size limit is 4KB. this won't suite me. now I want to create multiple cookies. I wanted to know if the 4KB limit applies for each of them and for example I can make 4 cookies each 4KB or it applies for all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LocalStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).  You can [reliably store and retrieve about 2.5 megabytes](http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/) of information per domain, across all browsers supporting HTML5.